# How to programmatically get the model of a TV?

Tags: java, android, android-tv

Here's the set-up: a smart TV box that runs android apps is connected to a TV. I want my app to be able to tell what the TV model is. If this were a smartphone the solution would be to simply use Build.MODEL but in this case Build.MODEL just yields the model of the TV box, not the TV itself. While looking at the settings menu with the remote I saw no mention of the TV model but surely the box must be aware of it? At the very least the resolution options it provides change with the capabilities of the TV hooked up to it.

Comment: This is a question that should be asked to the customer support department of your TV manufacturer.

Comment: No it shouldn't, this is a programming question as I have clearly said I want to program an app to be able to give that information. Customer support isn't going to tell me how to do that. God dammit this site is just awful for asking questions, only use of it is to browse Qs asked years ago. If  I ask something I get downvoted from people who can't even be bothered to read.and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could get specifications of TV box(an android device) via framework [APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware#check-features) .
The TV itself only is a **monitor**(screen) in this situation, using [DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics) could get some info such as `density`, `dpi`. But I don't think there is a way to get other parameters.